# Populate UITableView with Health data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, healthkit

I am trying to populate my tableview with data from Health app. The problem is that this data comes in different order every time I load the screen.

I have functions for getting the data from the Health app:

```
func readWalkrunDistance(startDate: NSDate) {
    healthManager.readRunningAndWalkingDistance(startDate, endDate: selectedDate!) { (results, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            var dict: [String: Double] = [String: Double]()
            dict["Walkrun Distance"] = results
            dict["number"] = 13
            if let result = results {
                self.walkrunDistance = result
            }
            self.healthData.append(dict)
            self.updateData()
        })
    }
}

func readBodyMass(startDate: NSDate) {
    healthManager.readMedianBodyMass(startDate, endDate: selectedDate!) { (results, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            var dict: [String: Double] = [String: Double]()
            dict["Body Mass"] = results
            dict["number"] = 7
            if let result = results {
                self.bodyMass = result
            }
            self.healthData.append(dict)
            self.updateData()
        })
    }
}
```

And another 10 functions like these for other Health data. The problem is that the data comes every time in different order, sometimes walkrunDistance is shown twice and etc. I think it is because of the async calls, but I don't know how to wait for these functions to get the data, then go to cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Here is my function for calling all the Health functions:

```
func readAllData() {
    selectedDate = ProjectManager.sharedInstance.chosenDate
    selectedDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: selectedDate, options: [])
    let startDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: selectedDate, options: [])
    self.readActiveEnergyBurned(startDate!)
    self.readBasalEnergyBurned(startDate!)
    self.readBloodAlcoholContent(startDate!)
    self.readBloodPressureDiastolic(startDate!)
    self.readBloodPressureSystolic(startDate!)
    self.readBodyFatPercentage(startDate!)
    self.readBodyMass(startDate!)
    self.readDistanceCycling(startDate!)
    self.readFlightsClimbed(startDate!)
    self.readAverageHeartRate(startDate!)
    self.readMinimumHeartRate(startDate!)
    self.readMaximumHeartRate(startDate!)
    self.readLeanBodyMass(startDate!)
    self.readStepCount(startDate!)
    self.readWorkouts(startDate!)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I want first to get the data, then load it into the tableview in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dispatch_group.

Here's link to tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2

- Just add `var group = dispatch_group_create()` variable into your class.
- Add `dispatch_group_enter(group)` into all of your functions and `dispatch_group_leave(group)` to the end of your async calls.

  `func readWalkrunDistance(startDate: NSDate) {
      healthManager.readRunningAndWalkingDistance(startDate, endDate: selectedDate!) { (results, error) -> Void in
          dispatch_group_enter(group)
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
              var dict: [String: Double] = [String: Double]()
              dict["Walkrun Distance"] = results
              dict["number"] = 13
              if let result = results {
                  self.walkrunDistance = result
              }
              self.healthData.append(dict)
              self.updateData()
              dispatch_group_enter(group)
          })
      }
  }`
- Add before `self.tableView.reloadData()` - `dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`

This will resolve your "async" problem. `-reloadData` will be called after all functions.

Comment: Yeap, you're right :)
replace `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in`